# Observablecollection not updating in Win Store App

Tags: c#

I have the code where i need to update observablecollection, but code don't work:

```
    _post = new ObservableCollection<Wall_Post>();
_post.Add(new Wall_Post {Server = "ss"});

lvMain.ItemsSource = _post;

HttpResponseMessage message = await client1.PostAsync(url, content1);

var item = _post.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Progress == "Visible");
if (item != null)
{
    item.Server = "111";
}
```

In previous quetion somebody answered me that this problem in await operator. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem is regarding the Server property and not the ObservableCollection (I hope I was right ;) )

Does Wall_Post implement the INotifyPropertyChanged?
Wall_Post should implement it and the Server property should be something like this:

```
    public string Server
    {
        get { return this._server; }
        set
        {
            if (this._server != value)
            {
                this._server = value;
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Server"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Problem not in Iproperty Changed interface

Comment: Are you sure that there is any item with `Progress == "Visible"`?